# sql select query not returning for some columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing, mamp

I am developing a web app using gwt. As part of the app I have created table that has 4 columsn: id, name, code, file. From some reason when I run the command

```
"SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE id = 3"
```

MAMP returns a result but when I run

```
"SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE code = 'A101'"
```

MAMP does not return anything and instead just shows a spinning loading icon. The same command works for the name column but does not work for the file column

Edit:

I added an index for code

Comment: How many rows in your table, and is there an index on `code`?

Answer (score 0):

`Code` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You should use back ticks around it.

```
"SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE `code` = 'A101'"
```

Comment: I tried adding the back ticks and it still does not work. i also tried renaming the column to cccode instead and that was still unsuccessful